# HTML Agility Pack strip tags NOT IN whitelist

Tags: c#, tags, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, sanitize

I'm trying to create a function which removes html tags and attributes which are not in a white list.
I have the following HTML:

```
<b>first text </b>
<b>second text here
       <a>some text here</a>
 <a>some text here</a>

 </b>
<a>some twxt here</a>
```

I am using HTML agility pack and the code I have so far is:

```
static List<string> WhiteNodeList = new List<string> { "b" };
static List<string> WhiteAttrList = new List<string> { };
static HtmlNode htmlNode;
public static void RemoveNotInWhiteList(out string _output, HtmlNode pNode, List<string> pWhiteList, List<string> attrWhiteList)
{

 // remove all attributes not on white list
 foreach (var item in pNode.ChildNodes)
 {
  item.Attributes.Where(u => attrWhiteList.Contains(u.Name) == false).ToList().ForEach(u => RemoveAttribute(u));

 }

 // remove all html and their innerText and attributes if not on whitelist.
 //pNode.ChildNodes.Where(u => pWhiteList.Contains(u.Name) == false).ToList().ForEach(u => u.Remove());
 //pNode.ChildNodes.Where(u => pWhiteList.Contains(u.Name) == false).ToList().ForEach(u => u.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(ConvertHtmlToNode(u.InnerHtml),u));
 //pNode.ChildNodes.Where(u => pWhiteList.Contains(u.Name) == false).ToList().ForEach(u => u.Remove());

 for (int i = 0; i < pNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
 {
  if (!pWhiteList.Contains(pNode.ChildNodes[i].Name))
  {
   HtmlNode _newNode = ConvertHtmlToNode(pNode.ChildNodes[i].InnerHtml);
   pNode.ChildNodes[i].ParentNode.ReplaceChild(_newNode, pNode.ChildNodes[i]);
   if (pNode.ChildNodes[i].HasChildNodes && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pNode.ChildNodes[i].InnerText.Trim().Replace("\r\n", "")))
   {
    HtmlNode outputNode1 = pNode.ChildNodes[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < pNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
    {
     string _childNodeOutput;
     RemoveNotInWhiteList(out _childNodeOutput,
          pNode.ChildNodes[i], WhiteNodeList, WhiteAttrList);
     pNode.ChildNodes[i].ReplaceChild(ConvertHtmlToNode(_childNodeOutput), pNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[j]);
     i++;
    }
   }
  }
 }

 // Console.WriteLine(pNode.OuterHtml);
 _output = pNode.OuterHtml;
}  

private static void RemoveAttribute(HtmlAttribute u)
{
 u.Value = u.Value.ToLower().Replace("javascript", "");
 u.Remove();

}

public static HtmlNode ConvertHtmlToNode(string html)
{
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(html);
 if (doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Count == 1)
  return doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[0];
 else return doc.DocumentNode;
}
```

The output I am tryig to achieve is

```
<b>first text </b>
<b>second text here
       some text here
 some text here

 </b>
some twxt here
```

That means that I only want to keep the `<b>` tags.
The reason i'm doing this is because Some of the users do cpoy-paste from MS WORD into ny WYSYWYG html editor.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

heh, apparently I ALMOST found an answer in a blog post someone made....

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Wayloop.Blog.Core.Markup
{
    public static class HtmlSanitizer
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, string[]> Whitelist;

        static HtmlSanitizer()
        {
            Whitelist = new Dictionary<string, string[]> {
                { "a", new[] { "href" } },
                { "strong", null },
                { "em", null },
                { "blockquote", null },
                };
        }

        public static string Sanitize(string input)
        {
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(input);
            SanitizeNode(htmlDocument.DocumentNode);

            return htmlDocument.DocumentNode.WriteTo().Trim();
        }

        private static void SanitizeChildren(HtmlNode parentNode)
        {
            for (int i = parentNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                SanitizeNode(parentNode.ChildNodes[i]);
            }
        }

        private static void SanitizeNode(HtmlNode node)
        {
            if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element) {
                if (!Whitelist.ContainsKey(node.Name)) {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                    return;
                }

                if (node.HasAttributes) {
                    for (int i = node.Attributes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        HtmlAttribute currentAttribute = node.Attributes[i];
                        string[] allowedAttributes = Whitelist[node.Name];
                        if (!allowedAttributes.Contains(currentAttribute.Name)) {
                            node.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (node.HasChildNodes) {
                SanitizeChildren(node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[I got HtmlSanitizer from here](http://thomasjo.com/blog/archive/a-pessimistic-html-sanitizer/)
Apparently it does not strip th tags, but removes the element altoghether.

OK, here is the solution for those who will need it later.

```
public static class HtmlSanitizer
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, string[]> Whitelist;
        private static List<string> DeletableNodesXpath = new List<string>();

        static HtmlSanitizer()
        {
            Whitelist = new Dictionary<string, string[]> {
                { "a", new[] { "href" } },
                { "strong", null },
                { "em", null },
                { "blockquote", null },
                { "b", null},
                { "p", null},
                { "ul", null},
                { "ol", null},
                { "li", null},
                { "div", new[] { "align" } },
                { "strike", null},
                { "u", null},                
                { "sub", null},
                { "sup", null},
                { "table", null },
                { "tr", null },
                { "td", null },
                { "th", null }
                };
        }

        public static string Sanitize(string input)
        {
            if (input.Trim().Length < 1)
                return string.Empty;
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(input);            
            SanitizeNode(htmlDocument.DocumentNode);
            string xPath = HtmlSanitizer.CreateXPath();

            return StripHtml(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.WriteTo().Trim(), xPath);
        }

        private static void SanitizeChildren(HtmlNode parentNode)
        {
            for (int i = parentNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                SanitizeNode(parentNode.ChildNodes[i]);
            }
        }

        private static void SanitizeNode(HtmlNode node)
        {
            if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (!Whitelist.ContainsKey(node.Name))
                {
                    if (!DeletableNodesXpath.Contains(node.Name))
                    {                       
                        //DeletableNodesXpath.Add(node.Name.Replace("?",""));
                        node.Name = "removeableNode";
                        DeletableNodesXpath.Add(node.Name);
                    }
                    if (node.HasChildNodes)
                    {
                        SanitizeChildren(node);
                    }                  

                    return;
                }

                if (node.HasAttributes)
                {
                    for (int i = node.Attributes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        HtmlAttribute currentAttribute = node.Attributes[i];
                        string[] allowedAttributes = Whitelist[node.Name];
                        if (allowedAttributes != null)
                        {
                            if (!allowedAttributes.Contains(currentAttribute.Name))
                            {
                                node.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            node.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                SanitizeChildren(node);
            }
        }

        private static string StripHtml(string html, string xPath)
        {
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            if (xPath.Length > 0)
            {
                HtmlNodeCollection invalidNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@xPath);
                foreach (HtmlNode node in invalidNodes)
                {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
                }
            }
            return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo(); ;
        }

        private static string CreateXPath()
        {
            string _xPath = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < DeletableNodesXpath.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != DeletableNodesXpath.Count - 1)
                {
                    _xPath += string.Format("//{0}|", DeletableNodesXpath[i].ToString());
                }
                else _xPath += string.Format("//{0}", DeletableNodesXpath[i].ToString());
            }
            return _xPath;
        }
    }
```

I renamed the node because if I had to parse an XML namespace node it would crash on the xpath parsing.

Comment: The link to HtmlSanitizer is broken.  This may be the code Meltdown is referring to: https://gist.github.com/814428

Comment: That is in no way the code from which I created the Whitelist validation class. The original author did not use RegEx. The original code of the author is the first piece of code I posted.

Comment: This code doesn't work, I can save a form with submit button easily as well as an script section that contains harmful code.

Comment: the following causes HTML Sanitizer to throw an exception - IOW, your users need to use well-formed HTML in order for this code to work as is:<img src=dfkl onerror="console.log('hisadfd');"

Comment: As others have stated, whilst useful, this is flawed. Harmful javascript can be injected into the href attribute

Comment: There are 2 similar projects, https://github.com/Vereyon/HtmlRuleSanitizer and https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer. The latter is linked to from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library with examples

Comment: Note that `DeletableNodesXpath` will always keep growing with the code above. It always add `"removableNode"` to the list and it will never match (because it is looking through a list full of "removableNode")

Comment: It is worth looking into `currentAttribute.DeEntitizeValue` to check if `<a href="javascript:"` is not injected.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the code - great thing!!!!

I did few optimization...

```
class TagSanitizer
{
    List<HtmlNode> _deleteNodes = new List<HtmlNode>();

    public static void Sanitize(HtmlNode node)
    {
        new TagSanitizer().Clean(node);
    }

    void Clean(HtmlNode node)
    {
        CleanRecursive(node);
        for (int i = _deleteNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            HtmlNode nodeToDelete = _deleteNodes[i];
            nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete, true);
        }
    }

    void CleanRecursive(HtmlNode node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (Config.TagsWhiteList.ContainsKey(node.Name) == false)
            {
                _deleteNodes.Add(node);
            }
            else if (node.HasAttributes)
            {
                for (int i = node.Attributes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    HtmlAttribute currentAttribute = node.Attributes[i];

                    string[] allowedAttributes = Config.TagsWhiteList[node.Name];
                    if (allowedAttributes != null)
                    {
                        if (allowedAttributes.Contains(currentAttribute.Name) == false)
                        {
                            node.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            node.ChildNodes.ToList().ForEach(v => CleanRecursive(v));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Config from this line? if (Config.TagsWhiteList.ContainsKey(node.Name) == false)

Comment: This is just another list, You can change it how you want :)

Comment: As a side note, when I tried this I ran into issues with the resulting markup being inconsistent (sections out of order, not all the formatting being properly stripped) likely due to the multi-threading optimization with the recursion.

Comment: Yes, This snippet is not have support for multitasking

Comment: This answer works for me so far. The accepted answer kept throwing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in the StripHtml method on the server I deployed it on. That proved too hard to debug as it would not throw the error on my local environment.