# HTML Agility Pack Fix <li> list order

Tags: c#, .net, html, html-agility-pack

I have been trying to use the HTML Agility Pack to parse HTML into valid XHTML to go into a larger XML file. This for the most part works however lists become formatted like:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1
    <li>item2
    </li></li>
</ul>
```

As oppose to what I would expect:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately this format with nested li tags doesn't pass the schema validation which I have no control over. Does anyone know a simple way to correct this either through the HTML Agility Pack or an alternative. Preferably in .NET.

Comment: Are you trying to parse invalid HTML at the end or is this the output of the HTML Agility pack>

Comment: Yes I am trying to parse invalid HTML using the agility pack. I thought the XHTML options in the agility pack would fix it, which technically it has in terms of matching start and end tags but not in the desired way.

Comment: LI end tags are optional, so this isn't (necessarily) due to invalid html, but rather the following HAP bug: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative to the agility pack called HTML Tidy http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ I actually used the .NET port called Tidy.NET http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/ this seemed to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found your questio on other sites as well. The HTML you are trying to parse is:

```
<UL>
<LI>NVQ Level 3 in Fabrication and Welding Engineering
<LI>Level 3 Certificate in Engineering
<LI>Level&nbsp;2 Key Skill in Application of Number
<LI>Level&nbsp;2 Key Skill in Communication
<LI>Level&nbsp;2 Key Skill in Information Technology
<LI>Level 2 Key Skill in Working with Others
<LI>Level 2 Key Skill in Improving Own Learning &amp; Performance</LI></UL>
```

What I notice is that the first `<li>` is parent to the other `<li>'s`.
One aproach I would take at this is to take the first `<li>` and the text (it's a TextNode for HAP), save the other `<li>` children and remove the children, inserting them (while formating them) after the parent node.
You might have to take the recursive way at this. Here is a peek at my solutuion for a HTML Sanitizer class: [HTML Agility Pack strip tags NOT IN whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist/3107567#3107567)

Answer (score -1):

```
    HtmlNode ul = _sourceForm.SelectSingleNode("//ul");
    HtmlNodeCollection childList = ul.ChildNodes;
```

Then you can loop though the child list to grab the text elements you are interested in.