# Stripping script tags from HTML input

Tags: c#, html, regex

```
public static string MakeWebSafe(this string x) {
    const string RegexRemove = @"(<\s*script[^>]*>)|(<\s*/\s*script[^>]*>)";
    return Regex.Replace(x, RegexRemove, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Is there any reason this implementation isn't good enough. Can you break it? Is there anything I haven't considered? If you use or have used something different, what are its advantages?

I'm aware this leaves the body of the script in the text, but that's okay for this project.

### UPDATE

Don't do the above! I went with this in the end: [HTML Agility Pack strip tags NOT IN whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist).

Comment: Instead of even *trying* to write a foolproof script and leaving open the possibility that you failed, why not just use an HTML parser like HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use a proven, solid security library.  See Chris's answer.

Comment: If/when I get time, I will come back and improve it, I just need a quick-and-dirty solution in place for the time being.

Comment: quick and dirty? It takes less than 5 minutes to download a library, add the reference to your project, and write a line or two that removes `<script>` elements from a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered this kind of scenario??

```
<scri<script>pt type="text/javascript">
    causehavoc();
</scr</script>ipt>
```

The best thing to do is remove all tags, encode things, or use bbcode

Comment: The only thing I want to prevent is any script actually running. It doesn't matter if its content or other leftovers survive for the project I am working on.

Comment: This is the point, you strip out the bits you want, the script will then get run as you only removed the inner script tags, not the invalid ones, which become valid one you remove the inner tags.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your RegEx can be circumvented by unicode encoding the script tags. I would suggest you look to more robust libraries when it comes to security. Take a look at [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Very good point. Since this is an internal tool, I only need to implement the most basic solution and get something up and running. This is beyond the skill of anyone that is going to use the tool (not the greatest of excuses I know, but I'm hoping I get time to come back and improve it later).

Comment: It would be safer to HtmlEncode the strings on the way out, that way none of the markup will execute. Take a look at the WPL, it is really easy to integrate and has some nice tools to get safe markup, which will allow some markup through that is considered safe.