# Using Regex to exclude HTML tags from the search without deleting the HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

Having done prior research on this question, [I understand that this is not a great way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) but I work for a company where deadlines are short and quality is... not really discussed. If this works 95 times out of 100, it is fine. Figuring out a parser is not in the time budget. I am also a junior dev and the senior devs abandoned this project, so my skill level is not high and I need this for tomorrow.

I have also found [plenty of solutions that remove the tags from the text selection,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559440/exclude-html-tags-in-javascript-regex) but I cannot do that either because another API later consumes the modified text to spit it out onto a webpage. The HTML tags must stay.

I am currently using this to find the words that I want in the HTML. Is there a way I can use Regex to modify it to not include words that are part of HTML tags/are HTML tags?

```
const reText = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
htmlPile = htmlPile.replace(reText, ‘<span>‘ + text + ‘</span>‘);
```

I assume that I can modify after `text` somehow, but how can I do that? So if say `text === 'span'` how do I make sure it doesn't include the span tags, or really any other word inside a `<>`?

I just need a 95 times out of 100 solution.

Sample input:

```
<span class=“span”>span</span>
```

Desired output:

```
<span class=“span”><span class=“formatting”>span</span></span>
```

Comment: I have a bunch of HTML. I need to programmically add <span> around certain words in that HTML. How can I find those words in the HTML without deleting any of the tags from it, but not including the HTML tags in the found results.

Comment: And why you're so into using RegExp for something you clearly understand RegExp is not meant for? What stops you from using a DOM parser? Why would a regular expression be a *must*.

Comment: I need it for tomorrow afternoon and haven’t a clue of where to start with a DOM parser.

Comment: Provide a code example of that you have, the input, the desired output and what you have tried. PS: what you added in comments is not exactly what you were asking for in your question.

Comment: What if you have `<span class="span">span <b>what about this?</b></span> ` ?

Comment: Ideally it would preserve the bolded content as well as what it bolded.

Comment: What means preserve? How would in such case the output look like?

Comment: <span class="span"><span class=“formatting”>span</span> <b>what about this?</b></span>

Like this.

Comment: Oh, than I understood it right. Provided an answer with a couple of examples. If you have questions about the code, don't just call it a day, ask what you don't understand ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, don't use RegExp to manipulate HTML.

Your task was nothing but wrapping the immediate [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) (of [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) **3**) into a `<span class="formatted">`.
For that task you might want to use [Node.replaceChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) after making sure you're  only operating over that specific nodeType 3

```js
const ELS_span = document.querySelectorAll(".span");
const NewEL = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

ELS_span.forEach(span => {
  const nodes = span.childNodes;
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      const EL_formatting = NewEL("span", {className: "formatting", textContent: node.textContent});
      span.replaceChild( EL_formatting, node );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.formatting {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<span class="span">format me <b>bold not interested in</b> and me</span>
```

If you want to get the text only, but not the content within the child nodes

```js
const EL_target = document.querySelector("#target");

const textOnly = [...EL_target.childNodes].reduce((a, b) => 
 a + (b.nodeType === 3 ? b.textContent : "")
, "");

console.log(textOnly); // "This is awesome!"
```

```html
<div id="target">
  This is <b>pretty</b> awesome
  <div>indeed</div>
  !
</div>
```

### Example with text search highlight

Using a search input to search for a specific word might be done using new Range to get a specific text range, collect ranges into an Array, and than replace those ranges with SPAN:

```js
const NewEL = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

const highlighter = (EL, word) => {

  let offset;
  const ranges = [];
  
  const createRange = (pos) => {
    const R = new Range();
    R.setStart(pos.node, pos.start);
    R.setEnd(pos.node, pos.end);
    ranges.push(R);
  };

  const rec = (node, str) => {
    const i = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());
    if (i < 0) return;
    const end = i + word.length;
    createRange({
      node,
      start: offset + i,
      end: offset + end
    });
    offset += end;
    rec(node, str.slice(end)); // Recursion!
  };

  EL.childNodes.forEach(node => {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      offset = 0;
      rec(node, node.textContent);
    }
  });

  ranges.forEach((R) => {
    const SPAN = NewEL("span", {
      className: "formatting",
      textContent: R.toString()
    });
    R.deleteContents();
    R.insertNode(SPAN)
  });
};

let EL_target = document.querySelector("#target");
const EL_target_HTML = EL_target.innerHTML;
const EL_search = document.querySelector("#search");
EL_search.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const val = EL_search.value;
  EL_target.innerHTML = EL_target_HTML; // Reset to previous HTML
  if (!val) return;
  highlighter(EL_target, val);
});
```

```css
.formatting {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
Search text only (no children elements):<br>
<input id="search" type="search" autocomplete=off>
<div id="target">
  Lorem ipsum <b>ignore this Lorem</b> Lorem and dolor lorem asd  this lorem
</div>
```

If you don't want to lose event listeners since the above's replacing of HTML with an older image of the previous HTML, use Range.getBoundingClientRect(); and highlight only the coordinates of those rects.

Comment: Where's the text search part?

Comment: @Phil I totally missed that! Will add into the answer - Thank you

Comment: I was not aware of the nodeTypes concept nor of thinking of HTML as a graph. That is extremely useful. For the text search, don't I just need to search the node.textContent for my word and replace it with the formatted span with the Word inside? Thanks!

Comment: @Labradoodle basically yes, To use RegExp here is tempting - but I'll try to get with a proper solution that uses indexing and separation.

Comment: @Labradoodle expanded with another example with text search