# Search a table field for a subscript of a string in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
**Description**
North
East
West
South
```

Now if I want to search the table in the column description using a subscript of a string like for example I want to search the value North but the available string I have is "ValueNorth"

its like this sample SQL:

```
SELECT Description FROM Table1 WHERE Description = 'ValueNorth'
```

Now what I want to display in the result is the value of North in the description.

Is it possible in SQL server.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you considered using `LIKE`?

Comment: SELECT Description FROM Table1 WHERE Description Like '%North%'

Comment: Please clarify your questions, it is not clear what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Um it's very hard to understand what you are asking but is this what you are looking for?

```
SQL> SELECT SUBSTRING('Quadratically',5,6);
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING('Quadratically',5,6)                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| ratica                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

as you can see it cuts up the string, more examples here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-string-functions.htm#function_substring-index

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the value percentage matching between two values and then get the results based on the condition.

This may help you.

[T-SQL Get percentage of character match of 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518695/t-sql-get-percentage-of-character-match-of-2-strings)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT replace (Description,'Value','') FROM Table1 WHERE Description = 'ValueNorth'
```