# How to find the percentage of characters that are matching between 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table,

```
ID  ShopName            LocationName
1   GreatMall           Great,Mall
2   Gingermall          Gingermall
3   MARK.HI             MARK,HI
4   GALLERY INC         GALLERY. INC
```

If the column `'ShopName' = 'LocationName'`, then i want to find, by how much percentage the value of the columns match. 
(or to find the ideal percentage to set the fuzzy matching)
For example, in the table where `ID = 2`, The value in the columns `'ShopName'` and `'LocationName'` are matching (`Gingermall = Gingermall`) then the percentage of the data matching is 100%. 
For `ID = 1`, the values dont match (`GreatMall <> Great,Mall`), then I want to know by what percentage the data doesnt match.

Comment: What do you mean by: 'by what percentage the data doesnt match.' Is this based on the number of characters that are different for example.

Comment: I think it's already answered here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518695/t-sql-get-percentage-of-character-match-of-2-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518695/t-sql-get-percentage-of-character-match-of-2-strings)

Comment: I am looking for percentage of character match of entire 2 columns in a single table

Comment: Yes, it is based on the number of characters that are different for example

Comment: What happens if the two strings as `'AAAB'` and `'ABBB'`.  Does the ordering matter?  So what about `'AAAB'` and `'BBAB'`?  Your problem is not well-specified.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully vetted this solution but it works for your data sample:

Setup

```
Create Table #tbl 
(
ID Int,
ShopName VarChar(25),
LocationName VarChar(25)
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,'GreatMall','Great,Mall'), 
(2,'Gingermall','Gingermall'), 
(3,'MARK.HI','MARK,HI'), 
(4,'GALLERY INC','GALLERY. INC')
```

Query

```
Declare @results As Table (id Int, ShopName VarChar(25), LocationName VarChar(25), mlength Int, charmatches Int)
Declare @sn VarChar(25)
Declare @ln VarChar(25)
Declare @id Int
Declare @cnts Int 
Declare @cnt Int 
Declare @samechars Int 

Declare vCursor Cursor
    For Select id, ShopName, LocationName From #tbl
Open vCursor
Fetch Next From vCursor Into @id, @sn, @ln

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
   Set @cnts = 1
   Set @cnt = 1
   Set @samechars = 0
   While @cnt <= Case When Len(@sn) > Len(@ln) Then Len(@sn) Else Len(@ln) End
   Begin
      If Substring(@sn,@cnts,1) = Substring(@ln,@cnt,1) 
      Begin
        Set @cnts = @cnts + 1   --Only move this forward if there is a match
        Set @samechars = @samechars + 1
      End
      Else If Substring(@sn,@cnt,1) = Substring(@ln,@cnt,1) Set @samechars = @samechars + 1
      Set @cnt = @cnt + 1
   End

   Insert Into @results Select @id, @sn As ShopName, @ln As LocationName, Case When Len(@sn) > Len(@ln) Then Len(@sn) Else Len(@ln) End As mlength, @samechars As CharMatches 
   Fetch Next From vCursor Into @id, @sn, @ln
End

Select *, (Cast(charmatches As Float)/Cast(mlength As Float)) * 100.0 As percentmatch   From @results

Close vCursor
DeAllocate vCursor
Drop Table #tbl
```

Results:

```
id  ShopName    LocationName    mlength charmatches percentmatch
1   GreatMall   Great,Mall      10      9           90
2   Gingermall  Gingermall      10      10          100
3   MARK.HI     MARK,HI         7       6           85.7142857142857
4   GALLERY INC GALLERY. INC    12      11          91.6666666666667
```