# SQL left join with best string match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join two tables with best match strings. Table A contains some values which do not match 100% with Table B.

But I want to join Table A with Table B having a maximum matching record.

Following is a sample of Table A, Table B, and required output with some logic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Following is the sample tables:

```
drop table if exists #C
CREATE TABLE #C(ID int, ReferenceID varchar (100))
insert into #C values

(1,'ABC123'),
(2,'456XYZ'),
(3,'5PQR3'),
(4,'789XYZ'),
(5,'789A')


drop table if exists #D
CREATE TABLE #D(ReferenceID varchar (100), FirstName varchar (100))
INSERT INTO #D VALUES
('XYZ','Olivia'),
('ABD123','Emma'),
('45XYZ','William'), 
('ABC456','Jackson')
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching` of [this post here on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518695/t-sql-get-percentage-of-character-match-of-2-strings). With this you could write the following:

```sql
select A.ID,A.ReferenceID, B.FirstName, [dbo].[GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching](A.ReferenceID  ,B.ReferenceID) as strMatch from Table1 as A
left outer join Table2 as B on [dbo].[GetPercentageOfTwoStringMatching](A.ReferenceID  ,B.ReferenceID) > 30
```

(I used Table1 and Table2 instead of #C and #D in your example)

Which gives the following output:

[image]

You still have to filter out the double first names in this example.