# C# extracting html only

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing

Basically i have a webpage with embedded css and JavaScript, so what i want to do is extract only the HTML itself, from texts to tables , images and what not.

So far i have the whole web page stored into a string called "html" the contents of this page is just the facebook hompepage for example,but as you will see there's all scripts and other embedded stuff which i don't want to have.

```
   HTMLEdit = //webpage I chose to store in here//
   string html = HTMLEdit.DocumentText;
   String result = "this i want to only contain the <head>,<body>,<foot>."
```

I am only interested in displaying the result witch only contains html, i don't want the JavaScript or css or any other stuff

I have looked at the agility pack but there's no documentation on there website to do this and this is my first ever c# project i have decided to make, so excuse my ignorance if i don't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question
[HTML Agility Pack strip tags NOT IN whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist)

Maybe adapt that answer, and drop link and script tags.

Comment: I have used regex to delet tags or maybe can i push the tags into another string? im trying to avoid using librarys for this

Comment: Checked the link, the solution and resources are not available on that page anymore, so it was a no go