# Custom Html Helper is not becoming avaliable in the View (Razor/Asp.Net MVC3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, html-agility-pack

I am trying to implement a Whitelist HTML Sanitizer using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). I want to create a reusable Html Helper that allows me to use it. I have other custom Html helpers that I am using that work just fine, but for some reason this one will not work. Every time I try and call it from a view it is unable to find the Sanitize method. The call I am trying to make is in a partial view and looks like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Sanitize(Model.Body))
```

My Html Helper Class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ProjectX.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class HtmlSanitizeHelpers
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, string[]> Whitelist;
        private static List<string> DeletableNodesXpath = new List<string>();

        static HtmlSanitizeHelpers()
        {
            Whitelist = new Dictionary<string, string[]> {
                { "a", new[] { "href" } },
                { "strong", null },
                { "em", null },
                { "blockquote", null },
                { "b", null},
                { "p", null},
                { "ul", null},
                { "ol", null},
                { "li", null},
                { "div", new[] { "align" } },
                { "strike", null},
                { "u", null},                
                { "sub", null},
                { "sup", null},
                { "table", null },
                { "tr", null },
                { "td", null },
                { "th", null }
                };
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString Sanitize(string input)
        {
            if (input.Trim().Length < 1)
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(input);            
            SanitizeNode(htmlDocument.DocumentNode);
            string xPath = HtmlSanitizeHelpers.CreateXPath();

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(StripHtml(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.WriteTo().Trim(), xPath));
        }

        private static void SanitizeChildren(HtmlNode parentNode)
        {
            for (int i = parentNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                SanitizeNode(parentNode.ChildNodes[i]);
            }
        }

        private static void SanitizeNode(HtmlNode node)
        {
            if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (!Whitelist.ContainsKey(node.Name))
                {
                    if (!DeletableNodesXpath.Contains(node.Name))
                    {                       
                        //DeletableNodesXpath.Add(node.Name.Replace("?",""));
                        node.Name = "removeableNode";
                        DeletableNodesXpath.Add(node.Name);
                    }
                    if (node.HasChildNodes)
                    {
                        SanitizeChildren(node);
                    }                  

                    return;
                }

                if (node.HasAttributes)
                {
                    for (int i = node.Attributes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        HtmlAttribute currentAttribute = node.Attributes[i];
                        string[] allowedAttributes = Whitelist[node.Name];
                        if (allowedAttributes != null)
                        {
                            if (!allowedAttributes.Contains(currentAttribute.Name))
                            {
                                node.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            node.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                SanitizeChildren(node);
            }
        }

        private static string StripHtml(string html, string xPath)
        {
            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            if (xPath.Length > 0)
            {
                HtmlNodeCollection invalidNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@xPath);
                foreach (HtmlNode node in invalidNodes)
                {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
                }
            }
            return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo(); ;
        }

        private static string CreateXPath()
        {
            string _xPath = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < DeletableNodesXpath.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != DeletableNodesXpath.Count - 1)
                {
                    _xPath += string.Format("//{0}|", DeletableNodesXpath[i].ToString());
                }
                else _xPath += string.Format("//{0}", DeletableNodesXpath[i].ToString());
            }
            return _xPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Credits for most of this code goes to the answer in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist).

Things I have already checked:

1. Namespace has been correctly defined in the Web.Config file. (I also know this since others in the namespace already work)
2. Have done a clean build of the project.
3. Restarted Visual Studio 2010.

Thoughts on why I cannot seem to call the method from the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have properly extended the HtmlHelper.

You are missing the following in your function definition:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Sanitize(this HtmlHelper helper, string input)
```

Check out this post on [Using Class Extensions to simplify your code with the UrlHelper](http://www.webistrate.com/mvc3-using-class-extensions-to-simplify-your-code-with-the-urlhelper/)

Comment: That was indeed the answer. Thank you. That totally slipped my mind.