# Input Validation - Regex to match scripts

Tags: regex, validation, xss

What are the Regex expressions that I would need to test a string against in order to make sure it doesn't contain any Javascript?

I'm using this [article](http://www.publicidentity.ca/strip-javascript-script-tags-out-of-html-using-regular-expressions/) as a starting point.

- Code in  blocks:

  `<script.*?>[\s\S]*?</.*?script>`
- ":javascript" code (e.g. `<a href="javascript:alert('hello')"`):

  `(?<=<.*)javascript.*:[^"]*`
- Event handlers within Html tags (e.g. `<div onmouseover=""`):

  `on\w+="[^"]*"`

Comment: You don't want to remove all mentions of javascript. That would be a bad idea.

Comment: I would do it the other way around, positively test for what you *do* want

Comment: I recommend using a DOM parser rather than regexes. [You can't parse HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). It's _trivial_ with a proper DOM parser at hand.

Comment: Also, you can't protect yourself from __malformed HTML__ (unclosed tags, runt closing tags...) this way.

Comment: -1 and voting to close as too localised. Since you are already using an HTML parser to verify the HTML is valid (do you???) knowing how to use regex to ensure it doesn't contain javascript is _not useful_.

Comment: No I'm not using an HTML parser to verify the HTML is valid.

Comment: @IanWarburton then you have other issues to face than just cross-site scripting. No regex ever can fix unbalanced HTML. Consider if I sent this rich-text content: `</div></div></div></div>`. I'm pretty sure it would basically kill your design _and_ your page javascript.

Comment: So I should check for the existence of '<' and '>' in a string and then run a DOM parser on the string and use the result of that to look for script elements?

Comment: Just feed your entire string to the DOM parser, crawl the DOM for any active elements, remove them, and export back to string. This will balance your HTML on the go. As a bonus, it might even strip some unneccessary whitespace.

Comment: Cool. I would prefer not to run that on every string though because my input validation runs for *every* form value sent to a CMS. What would be a simple way to check that a value at least contains some tags?

Comment: @IanWarburton Even if it doesn't, you should _still_ HTML-escape all contents that needs to be. Again, the DOM parser fixes that for you.

Comment: Also, why is it a bad idea to remove all mentions of Javascript?

Comment: @IanWarburton then you wouldn't be able to write this question.

Comment: HTML-parse the inputs that can contain HTML and HTML-escape those that cannot. That's all you should do. Don't worry about performance. DOM parsing isn't slow.

Comment: Note that you should have a whitelist of tags, rather than a blacklist. Here are some other tags that you wouldn't like injected: `embed`, `video`, `audio`, `object`, `applet`, `form` and the related tags (most likely), ... and more are sure to come.

Comment: (I only get to say whether a string is valid or not. This is for a custom RequestValidator for ASP.net.) Anyhow, so I parse all values and reject any values that contain DOM elements that aren't on the white list or DOM elements with event handlers!

Comment: @IanWarburton If your DOM parser is able to die on malformed HTML, you can use it to validate. The ones that I've worked with lack that ability. If this is the case of your parser, then you need to _filter_ your inputs rather than _validate_ them with a DOM parser.

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ - "The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML.". That sounds like it prides itself on not dying. So what is the different between filtering and validating? Can't  I just compare all the tags in the DOM with the ones in the white list and reject the whole string if a non-match is found?

Comment: Or use this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist and just compare the length of the string before and after?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23215/discussion-between-jan-dvorak-and-ian-warburton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever use regexes to parse HTML. You might be able to ensure it does'n contain javascript, but you can't ensure it won't be horribly broken in other ways. Instead, use a proper parser.

Also, even valid HTML that doesn't contain javascript can still contain other unpleasant elements (audio, video, CSS nodes, form elements...), I recommend using a whitelist for the HTML elements that you do allow.

Here's an example of how your code could look like (note that even though it's supposed to be pseudocode, this might actually be proper C# syntax):

```
string[] tagWhitelist = ['strong', 'em', 'span' /*, ...*/];
string[] attrWhitelist = [/*...*/];

void function fixNode(DOMNode node, bool dieOnError){
   if(tagWhitelist.contains(node.type()){
      node.children.each((x) => fixNode(x))
      node.attributes
         .filter((x) => !attrWhitelist.contains(x))
         .each((x) => dieOnError ? throw new InvalidTagException() : x.remove())
   }else{
      dieOnError ? throw new InvalidAttrException() : node.remove()
   }
}

...

string output = fixNode(DOMParser.load(input, {strict:false}), false).toString();
```

This can also be used for validation, but *only* if the parser is able to throw an exception on invalid HTML (the ones I've worked with always try to fix the code):

```
try{
   // note: if fixNode is only ever used to validate, don't use exceptions
   fixNode(DOMParser.load(input, {strict:true}), true);
   return true;
}catch(InvalidTagException, InvalidAttrException ex){
   return false;
}
```

Update: the code you have linked in the comment claims to do exactly this, but I cannot guarantee it actually does.