# drawbacks of using ValidateRequest=“false” asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-2.0

I have a asp.net page with text editor. I am passing html to server side. So I started getting error like potentially dangerous script.

So I google it and found a solution on this site

```
ValidateRequest=“false”
```

with above code in page directive solved the error but I like to know if there any drawbacks to using ValidateRequest=“false”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should now be mindful of XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attacks. ValidateRequest=true protected you against XSS by disallowing potentially dangerous HTML script tags. I would suggest that you disable ValidateRequest only for the pages where you accept HTML. This can be done using this directive at the top of the page.

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" %>.
```

Even in the cases where you accept html, on the C# side you would want to do some processing to sanitize the HTML you received by maintaining a whitelist. This article is a good resource for a simple HTML sanitizer - [HTML Agility Pack strip tags NOT IN whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist)

Comment: how can I disable ValidateRequest only for the endpoints where you accept HTML. What do u mean by endpoints?

Comment: Clarified the answer a bit more. Hope it helps!