# Sanitizing Html on Backend

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sanitization

Using Web API 2 / Entity Framework with C#. We let a user generate some html on the client, save it to db, and then other users can get this html string from db and view it as html.

How can I "sanitize" this html on the backend. Is literally looking for the `<script>` tag in the saved html string that gets sent from the client before saving it to db enough, or is there a world of complexity that I am completely missing?

I don't care if they link random images, video, etc btw, the ONLY concern is them running scripts. Is `<iframe>` an issue btw, in the sense of "Can it access  the user's cookies?"

Comment: _'How can I "sanitize" this html on the backend'_ I would suggest finding a library to do so rather than rolling your own (as yes, there is a world of complexity - things can be injected in the strangest of places), as they will already have fixed the mistakes that are otherwise guarantee to happen.  Asking for library recommendations is off topic for Stack Overflow though, so....

Comment: You can look at: http://web.archive.org/web/20100901160940/http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html. Or look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist

Comment: In general, white-listing what the user *can* use is a far more effective security practice than black-listing what the user *can not* use.  The latter approach has no end game, you'll always be modifying the black list.

Comment: @David: This whole problem is caused by the fact that the project owner wants a ridiculous amount of functionality that's over-whelming front-end sanitation (some ghetto derivative of angular's ngSanitize).

Comment: @VSO: It's a frustrating problem, I'm sure.  Though a ridiculous amount is still a finite amount.  If the directive is literally "everything except script tags" then you can't guarantee security.  If the directive is "security" then the project needs to define the finite body of functionality to be tested and validated.