# Ensure safety before showing HTML email bodies in browser

Tags: html, vb.net, email, security, html-agility-pack

I'm working on an assistant (written in VB.NET for Winforms) to help screening and distribution of incoming e-mails inside my organization, which is and will continue to be made by human employees (I just need to speed up their work). Program will convert each message to HTML document and its attachments to PDF and will store it in internal database. This part is already working.

I'm already using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to handle inline images (`src="cid:..."`), but I'm worried about what can I do to prevent malicious content inside the message can be activated when showing it (in a .NET's WebBrowser control).

I thought of two things I could do, also with *HtmlAgilityPack*:

- removal of every `<script>` element;
- changing of every `<a href="...">` attribute to `"#"`

Can anyone who is more experienced with this issue suggest additional steps I should take on this "cleansing" of each message's HTML?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Antivirus programs for Email Servers also can do these things. You can set up your own rules to filter what you don't want. Plus those programs will always be up to date with latest threats in cyber world

Comment: These emails are already checked by my organization's antivirus. Sometimes i've seen phishing messages to pass thru, however. Do you think it is safe not to do anything else?

Comment: Generally, antivirus and quarantine software are 2 things that should installed on email server. Antivirus will take care of things in your question. Quarantine software will take care of things like spams, phishing, and mails from known malicious domains. If you write code for this, it will be a product in itself.

Comment: Well, I see your point and agree. I was thinking of some easy things I could do as an extra layer, because i don't 100% trust the antimalware software my org uses...

Comment: There are a lot more than that to look at, all the onchange, onclick, onload, onerror, ..., all the browser specific event. I think this is a problem that would be very hard to properly solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extra layer of security you can:

- check embedded URLs with an URL scanner. I suggest UrlVoid, they have an [API](http://www.urlvoid.com/api/) too (pointless if you have already a proper virus scanner).
- As suggested, you can remove all `script` and additional all `style` blocks:

  `Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
  doc.LoadHtml(html)
  doc.DocumentNode.Descendants.Where(() => {  }, ((n.Name = "script")  _
  OrElse (n.Name = "style"))).ToList.ForEach(() => {  }, n.Remove)`
- parse out any unwanted attributes to elements you don't want to allow, like `onclick()` and other javascript events.
- remove other unwanted tags: [HTML Agility Pack strip tags NOT IN whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist)

Note: There are a lot of powerful PHP HTML sanitizer/purifier. You can play around with them to do some quick tests (or even use one to pre-process your content). Most often [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison) is recommended.

Comment: Dumb question of mine: why are **style** tags dangerous?

Comment: The danger can arise from [XSS without User Interaction from passive Elements](https://html5sec.org/). Basically, it's another way to execute JavaScript.